# Absolute Summability of Coefficients of MA(inf) representation of stationary AR(p)

Tags: time-series, convergence, autoregressive, moving-average

Not self-study. This is more of a maths question:

Let $\Phi(B)X_t = e_t$ be a (weakly) stationary process. Let $$\Phi(B) = \prod_{i=1}^p (1-\alpha_iB)$$ So from stationarity we will have $|\alpha_i|<1$ for all $i$.

Representing as $MA(\infty)$:

\begin{align}
X_t &= \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^p (1-\alpha_iB)}e_t \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^p \Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\alpha_i^jB^j\Bigg)e_t \\
&=\Theta(B)e_t
\end{align}

My question is whether we can say that $\sum_i^\infty|\theta_i|<\infty?$, where $\theta_i$ are coefficients of the polynomial $\Theta(B)$.

I tried this:

\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^p \Bigg(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\alpha_i^jB^j\Bigg) =1&+\Bigg( \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i \Bigg) B + \Bigg( \sum_{i,j=1}^p \alpha_i\alpha_j \Bigg) B^2 + \Bigg(\sum_{i,j=1}^p \alpha_i^2\alpha_j \Bigg) B^3 \\ &+ \Bigg(\sum_{i,j=1}^p \alpha_i^3\alpha_j + \sum_{i\neq j}^p\alpha_i^2\alpha_j^2 \Bigg) B^4 + \dots \\ &+ \Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\sum_{i\neq j}^p \alpha_i^{(n-k)}\alpha_j^k \Bigg) B^n +\dots
\end{align}

Now WLOG let for some $m$,  $1\leq m \leq p$, $\alpha_m = \max \{\alpha_i\}$.

\begin{align}
|\theta_n| &\leq \Bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\sum_{i,j=1}^p |\alpha_i|^{(n-k)}|\alpha_j|^k \Bigg) \\
& \leq n|\alpha_m|^n 
\end{align}

Which would give that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |\theta_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty i|\alpha_m|^i < \infty$$

Is this correct? It seems like an important result which I couldn’t find in some standard texts.